# Shopify API Python - Inventory Level Set Error

Tags: python, shopify

Hoping you can be of help. I am building a basic API to set inventory levels on Shopify. New at this stuff so I am sure it's not great coding :(

I believe all the `location_id`, `inventory_item_id` are correct along with all my env variables.

```
import shopify
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
merchant = os.getenv('MERCHANT')

session = shopify.Session(merchant, '2023-04', token)
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

def set_inventory_level():
    shopify.InventoryLevel.set(78463762749, 44730407518525, 555, disconnect_if_necessary=True)

set_inventory_level()
```

I am getting this error:

> "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"

Any help would be massively appreciated

I have tried multiple different items and a lot more things that I can't remember